# Add custom table headers in table of content using tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm new to latex and this is my first time using it to write my report. I want to style my Table of contents and list of figure like the following images-

table of contents- 
[image: table of contents page]

list of figures- 
[image: list of figures page]

I have no idea where to start and how to format toc and tof like this. I would greatly appreciate your guidance and expertise.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Which document calss do you employ?

Comment: @Mico `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, final]{report}`